# Unable to render pbf tiles extracted from osm2vectortiles

Tags: osm2vectortiles

I have downloaded an mbtile file from osm2vectortiles (http://osm2vectortiles.org/downloads/) project. After that I have extracted pbf tiles using mbutil and tiles were successfully written to the disk. I have configured nginx to serve the static tiles with appropriate header information but my client (tangram https://mapzen.com/products/tangram/) is not able to render these tiles. It is neither throwing any errors nor debug information.

Answer (score 2):

The vector tiles inside the MBTiles file are gzipped. For some static servers you need to unzip them before serving them.